# :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-multidex

I have tried the following links

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html

[UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798816/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)

[com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

[':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: when i added Facebook latest SDK in my studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095536/apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-com-android-build-transform-api-transf)

[Android Studio TransformException : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915955/android-studio-transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransf)

[Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle/30692005#30692005)

[com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

My gradle build file is as below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appId"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/rt.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

My manifest is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packageName">

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity file is as below.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

After all this, I still get the following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task
':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Scroll up a bit more in the messages window where you found that error. There might be a more useful error message saying what went wrong.

Comment: Hi George, following is my stack trace. There is nothing wrong here. I am Android Studio noob.

Comment: Are you working on adding the full message displayed to the post? I do not see it there yet.

Comment: Hi @george-mulligan, following is my stack trace. I am Android Studio noob. I don't find anything wrong. All the other :app:<commands> shown as UP-TO-DATE

    :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug
    Preparing output jar [E:\AndroidStudioProjects\MADS\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar]
   Copying resources from program jar [E:\AndroidStudioProjects\MADS\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
 :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

Comment: Why do you have `rt.jar` as a dependency?

Comment: I want it to use ScriptEngine for evaluating math expression. rt.jar contains the java.script.*. Hence, rt.jar is a dependency.

Comment: Just out of curiosity does it work without it?

Comment: Nope, the build fails without rt.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**

I had to do the following at the app level

- Remove rt.jar as library
- Remove `compile files('libs/rt.jar')` from build.gradle
- Clean and build project.

Thanks to George Mulligan for pointing it out.

Comment: How to do it. Please provide more details

Comment: I achieved via cordova clean and build project.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a quick fix. But there might be a better solution to this.

> ***changing minSdkVersion means it will not gonna work for below the sdk version***

Under your Android folder look for you build.gradle file. Replace the minSdkVersion to 21. The code for it should look like this

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
}
```

thanks to [Edward Beazer](https://www.edwardbeazer.com/execution-failed-for-task-app-transformclasseswithmultidexlistfordebug/)

Comment: Thanks you very much. I don't know what's the problem but it's worked :)

Comment: welcome, but we need some fix that will work on minSdkVersion 16...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the same for the Windows OS with straight JAVA. I was having the same issue with `cordova run android` and it always fail in Mac. So I added the following to my build.gradle file and the build passed, and I was able to test on the emulator. Add your compiled info under android section and multidex under default config

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23"
}

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Notice the build is just 23 and not 23.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I know it is passed. but I had same problem.
the message was this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:...app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:....\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\eadf2be3981e05166424b72b4128200e\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$1.class]))

I searched a lot but nothing found.
I resolved it by adding below line to gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
```